# open() не видит изображение в директории, картинка существует

Tags: python

Интерпретатор сообщает, что файла не существует, хотя на самом деле лежит в нужной директории.

Есть код:

```
def upload_photo_on_server(self) -> ServerData:
    upload_url = self.get_upload_server()
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    rel_path = "Temp/time.jpeg"
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
    print("IMG PATH: ", abs_file_path)
    file = {
     'method': "POST",
     'file': ('time.jpeg', open(abs_file_path, 'rb')),
    }
    resp = post(upload_url, files=file)
    print("GET RESPONSE: ", resp)
```

Выбивает ошибку при открытии файла:

```
IMG PATH:  /home/ovsenka/Python projects/PhotoTimePy/Temp/time.jpeg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ovsenka/Python projects/PhotoTimePy/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ovsenka/Python projects/PhotoTimePy/main.py", line 18, in main
    client.upload_photo_on_server()
  File "/home/ovsenka/Python projects/PhotoTimePy/vk_api_service.py", line 50, in upload_photo_on_server
    'file': ('time.jpeg', open(abs_file_path, 'rb')),
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ovsenka/Python projects/PhotoTimePy/Temp/time.jpeg'
```

Однако до выполнения функции файл уже существует:
[image: Картинка time.jpeg существует]

Такие права у файла:

[image: Права time.jpeg]

Comment: `abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)` - какой именно ПОЛНЫЙ ПУТЬ выдаёт? обратитесь к файлу по абсолютному пути - все заработает

Comment: Я и обратился по абсолютному, я даже вывел в консоль этот путь

Comment: Может я слепой какой? Там же правильный абсолютный путь...

`print("IMG PATH: ", abs_file_path)`
Вывод: `IMG PATH:  /home/ovsenka/Python projects/PhotoTimePy/Temp/time.jpeg`

Comment: абсолютный путь - это "c:\\mydir\\home..." ну и т.д., разве нет?

Comment: Так у меня linux, а не windows

Comment: У вас у файла расширение есть?

Comment: Сейчас попробую time поменять на time.jpeg

Comment: Да, действительно там создается файл по имени time, но он как бы jpeg и открывается как картинка, а open искал time.jpeg, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение проблемы**

Изменить имя файла ***time*** на ***time.jpeg***, или сохранять файл с именем `time.jpeg`, или прописать это:

`rel_path = "Temp/time"`

Оказывается, `time.jpeg` и `time` это 2 разных файла, а функция `open` хотела найти по имени **time.jpeg**, поэтому не получалось найти, хотя файл `time` это тоже картинка и она была jpeg формата и прекрасно открывалась.